# JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSNumber (snapToOffsets)

Tags: react-native, flatlist

I have created a horizontal list in which `snapsToOffsets` according to the offset size. Although I keep getting the following error:
`JSON value '<null>' of type NSNull cannot be converted to NSNumber`
Which I believe to be from snapToOffsets (since removing does not show the error anymore) of something related to Typescript.

```
import { styles } from './styles'
import { Button } from '@/components'
import { useTheme } from '@react-navigation/native'
import React, { memo, useState } from 'react'
import { Dimensions, Image } from 'react-native'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { Asset, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker'

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width

const Component = () => {
  const { colors, spacing } = useTheme()
  const style = styles(colors, spacing)
  const [images, setImages] = useState<Asset[]>([])

  const handleDocuments = async () => {
    const result = await launchImageLibrary({
      mediaType: 'photo',
    })

    if (result?.assets) setImages([...result?.assets, ...images])
  }
  return (
    <FlatList
      style={style.list}
      contentContainerStyle={style.listContent}
      horizontal
      pagingEnabled
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      snapToAlignment="start"
      scrollEventThrottle={16}
      decelerationRate={'fast'}
      snapToOffsets={[
        ...Array(images.length).map((x, i) => {
          return i * (screenWidth - 60) + (i - 1) * 60
        }),
      ]}
      data={images}
      ListFooterComponent={() => (
        <Button
          type="default"
          onPress={handleDocuments}
          icons={{
            leftIcon: {
              name: 'file-upload',
              size: 30,
              color: colors.lightGray,
            },
          }}
          style={[style.container, { width: screenWidth - 40 }]}
        />
      )}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={{ uri: item.uri }}
            alt="d"
            style={{
              width: screenWidth - 60,
              marginHorizontal: 10,
              borderRadius: 10,
            }}
          />
        )
      }}
    />
  )
}

export const UploadField = memo(Component)
```

The error only happens when there is content on the list